# Configure Woocommerce Session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to search online a way on how to extend woocommerce to keep the session a bit longer but I can't find any good site to do this, is there anyway to fix woocommerce session so it would keep the session longer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set wordpress woocommerce cart expiration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812123/set-wordpress-woocommerce-cart-expiration)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php