# How to clear an abandoned woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I came across this code for clearing a Woocommerce cart on certain page loads.

But, I wonder is there a way to clear the cart after it has been abandoned?

> For triggering only on front page your function needs to look like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_front_page() && isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
```

> }
>   function is_front_page() returns true only on front page of your wordpress site. Also, you might detect any other page with function is_page() where you can pass any page title, ID or slug

Comment: How do define 'abandoned' and how should we test for that?

Comment: i suppose if there was some timer that cart contents hadn't got to checkout after a certain number of minutes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this question: [Set WooCommerce Cart Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812123/set-wordpress-woocommerce-cart-expiration/20508981#20508981)

> From what I can see, WooCommerce 2.0.20 has a scheduled maintenance job that runs twice/day that will remove any cart sessions from the WordPress options table. The default expiration time is set to 48 hours from the time the user first created the cart. I'm guessing your standard WordPress scheduling routines (and server cron/at jobs) will need to be running properly for this to execute.
>
> AFAIK there is no way to adjust the 48 hour rule via settings. You could write a filter in your theme or in an "adjacent" plugin.

I've adjusted the code a little bit to switch to a 24 hour session. I'm not sure you want to be deleting every few minutes as that has the potential to be performance-heavy.

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring', 'so_26545001_filter_session_expiring' );

function so_26545001_filter_session_expiring($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 23; // 23 hours
}

add_filter('wc_session_expiration', 'so_26545001_filter_session_expired' );

function so_26545001_filter_session_expired($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hours
}
```

Comment: It _is_ 5 year old code. However, those filters still appear to be in WC core and still responsible for determining the length of time to preserve a user's session.