# Woocommerce Set Cart Expiration Interval

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need to increase the expiration time of Woocommerce cart to 72 hours.

I've tried the solution suggested here: [set wordpress woocommerce cart expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812123/set-wordpress-woocommerce-cart-expiration)

But I can't see any result :(
Can anyone help me to get this working?

Thanks

-- Edit: Code snippet ---

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring' );
add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired' );

function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return (60 * 60 * 24 * 4) - (60 * 60);
}
function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
   return 60 * 60 * 24 * 4;
}
```

Comment: You can post code in your question. Which snippet did you try?

Comment: Hi Helga!Thank you for your reply
I've edited my question whit the snippet

I have not used the "WoocommerceLicenseAPI" like suggested in original question, because it's not very clear to me and I get some errors...

Really I don't understand how Woocommerce manage cart expiration period, can you help me to find some docs that explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter must return 72 hours, in seconds.

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring' );
add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired' );

function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 71;
}
function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
   return 60 * 60 * 72;
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I'll try this snippet ...
Can I just add in the functions.php file of my theme, right?

After that every 72 hours the cart of all users will be deleted?
Did I get it right? :)

Comment: Hello, I did a little research and I was wondering if this Woocommerce feature is based on Wordpress Cron system ...?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly this problem in a multi site set up and built a plugin to solve this. You can get the plugin here http://mtrl.co.uk/shop/product/woocommerce-cart-lifespan-settings-plugin/