# How can I extend shopping cart lifetime without modifying session expiration?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to extend the lifetime of WooCommerce shopping cart for users with accounts. The suggested solutions that I've found (and tried) involve extending the session expiration.

[Woocommerce Set Cart Expiration Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167646/woocommerce-set-cart-expiration-interval)

However, this is not what I'm after. I would like the session expiration to stay the same, but the next time the user logs in I would like their cart to remain for up to six months.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Then you will have to store the cart on your database. I would expect that WooCommerce would have an option for that

Answer (score 0):

The session expiration and the cart expiration are linked: they both use the same internal variable (a protected property of class `WC_Session_Handler`, `$_session_expiration`).

You can’t change one and not the other.

Removing the cart from the database is done by `WC_Session_Handler->cleanup_sessions()`. This is invoked by the function `wc_cleanup_session_data()` which is triggered by the `woocommerce_cleanup_sessions` action .

You might try to remove the default action and provide your own.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cleanup_sessions', 'wc_cleanup_session_data' );

function my_cleanup_sessions() 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $this->_table WHERE session_expiry < %d", time() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) );

    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Cache_Helper' ) ) {
        WC_Cache_Helper::incr_cache_prefix( WC_SESSION_CACHE_GROUP );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cleanup_sessions', 'my_cleanup_sessions' );
```

**I have not tested this.** It might not work and there might be side effects.

Comment: It's amazing to me that WooCommerce doesn't have an option to maintain carts beyond the current session. All the big vendors do this. Nobody on WC wants to?