# How to expire WooCommerce cart within 5 minutes? Trying to use filter hook but can't make it work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove the content of carts after 5 minutes instead of the defined 48 hours of WooCommerce.

I have added the code below to my site

```
add_filter( 'wc_session_expiration', function($seconds){ return 300;} );
add_filter( 'wc_session_expiring', function($seconds){ return 299;} );
```

but nothing is happening, I even checked the wp_woocommerce_sessions table and see that the session_expiry of new entry is more than a day.

Comment: By default WooCommerce sets 48 hours. You need to set a custom function with plugin.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812123/set-woocommerce-cart-expiration

Comment: that's exactly what i did, added a custom function. But the filter hook is not working